# Selenium-Cucumber-Jenkins execute using combination of tags

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

Good day! I would like to ask regarding execution of test scenarios using combination (ANDed / ORed) of "Tags". I want to execute **Scenario 1** with tags "@Priority1" and "@ModuleA". I tried to use the list below, but I'm not able to execute the specific scenario. See details below:

Used Tags in Jenkins

1. @Priority1,@ModuleA
2. @Priority1 @ModuleA
3. "@Priority1","@ModuleA"
4. "@Priority1" "@ModuleA"

**Scenarios**

Scenario 1 - @Priority1 @ModuleA

Scenario 2 - @Priority2 @ModuleA

Scenario 3 - @Priority3 @ModuleA

Scenario 4 - @Priority1 @ModuleB

[image]

[image]

I would like to ask for your guidance regarding this matter. Thank you in advance for the answers. :)

Comment: making this thread up!

Comment: Making this thread up

Comment: Making this thread up!